# log2conosle remoting appender for log4net doesnt work

Tags: .net, logging, log4net, log4net-appender, log4net-configuration

i have the following app.config:

```
 <log4net>
  <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="S3Logger.log"/>
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <appender name="RemotingAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RemotingAppender" >
    <sink value="tcp://localhost:7070/LoggingSink" />
    <lossy value="false" />
    <bufferSize value="1" />
  </appender>

  <!-- Setup the root category, add the appenders and set the default level -->
  <root>
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="RemotingAppender" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

and the following code behind:

```
   public partial class App : Application
{
    NameValueCollection appConfig = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
    private readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(App));
    private TaskbarIcon tb;

    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        //initialize NotifyIcon
        if (getServiceStatus() == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
        {
            tb = (TaskbarIcon)FindResource("ActiveServiceIcon");
        }
        else
        {
            tb = (TaskbarIcon)FindResource("InactiveServiceIcon");
        }
        log.Debug("Icon Created");

    }

}
```

for some reason  i get the logging only in file but not via log2console ".net remoting reciever" any idea why?

(i am using vs2012 and log4net installed via nuget)

Comment: Are you sure log2console is configured the way you think it's configured?

Comment: .Net Remoting:
Append Host Name to Logger:  True
Remote sink name: LoggingSink
Remote TCP Port Number: 7070

Answer (score 1):

Same issue for log4net remoting appender, all settings are correct, but Log2Console just keep silent.
Try UDP appender, its works fine for me.

Config:

```
<appender name="UdpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.UdpAppender">
   <remoteAddress value="127.0.0.1" />
   <remotePort value="7071" />
   <layout type="log4net.Layout.XmlLayoutSchemaLog4j" />
</appender>
```

Log2Console receiver:

[image: Log2Console receiver]